# Variable not defined even being globally defined

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

So i have this function, i'm declaring the var togglesmall globally, and i'm getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: togglesmall is not defined"

```
$(document).ready(function(){
if ( !$('.sound,.sound-small').hasClass('clickd') || $('.sound').hasClass('gone') ){

$('body').on('mouseleave', function(){
togglesmall = setTimeout(function(){$('.sound-small').fadeOut()}, 2000);
});

$('body').on('mouseenter', function(){
clearTimeout(togglesmall);
$('.sound-small').fadeIn(500);
});
};

$('.sound').on('click', function(){
$('.sound').fadeOut(1000);
$('.sound').addClass('clickd');
});
});
```

It's not the first time I receive it, but I never know why it happens.

I'm learning js so i'm pretty newbie. The whole code was written by me, so if you have any sugestions i appreciate.

Comment: Is togglesmall initialized to a value or only declared? Can you include the code where you do this declaration?

Comment: If you want to use global variables, use `window.togglesmall`. Using `togglesmall` without declaration is discouraged and not valid in strict mode.

Comment: I sure don't see any explicit definition of that variable in your code. If you're relying on the implicit declaration, it only happens on `mouseleave`, which will typically take place *after* `mouseenter`, which reads that variable. So when the `mouseenter` happens first, the implicit declaration hasn't happened yet and you get the error.

Comment: Didn't I declare in the line 5? togglesmall = setTimeout...
I tried to put window.togglesmall instead of togglesmall and i get the same error.

Comment: ***even being globally defined*** this is not true, you did not define it globally.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare togglesmall at the top like this:

```
var togglesmall = null;
```

Or else, the scope of the variable becomes ambiguous.

Comment: Declaring a variable without storing a value directly is done via `var togglesmall;`

Comment: That would be initialized as undefined which isn't safe. In Javascript, it's a good practice to initialize variable with default value.

Comment: `null` isn't safer than `undefined`. And especially in this case it's no problem to have `undefined` instead: `clearTimeout(undefined)` works just as well as `clearTimeout(null)`.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting a `ReferenceError` because

```
togglesmall = setTimeout(...)
```

is doing [global assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description) which creates that variable only **after** this code is run.

Doing something like:

```
if (typeof togglesmall != 'undefined')
  clearTimeout(togglesmall)
```

will fix your `ReferenceError`.

OR, as David W Lee recommended:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var togglesmall;  // add this; defines the variable and initializes to undefined
```

---

**Fun fact:** doing global assignment like you're doing with

```
previousUndeclaredName = value;
```

without first encountering something like

```
var previousUndeclaredName;
```

or being in the arguments list

```
function doSomething(previousUndeclaredName) {
```

will *always* be a `ReferenceError` in strict mode.[1]

[1] https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var#Description

Answer (score 0):

To make the variable globally defined, you need to create it when the document is ready. So it must be like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var togglesmall;
    ........
    // continue your code below
});
```

Comment: Declaring a variable without storing a value directly is done via `var togglesmall;`

Answer (score 0):

You need to create it when document is ready. like below...

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var togglesmall;
    //yourode
});
```